# Is it possible to convert a Database Access 97 to Access 2003 using VB6?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have a project in VB6 with a DB Access 97.

I need to convert the format to Access 2003 or newer.

Is this possible using VB6 code?

Comment: Not 100% sure what your question is.  Do you mean: (1) I have an Access 97 database that I want to convert to Access 2003?; or (2) I want to use VB6 to convert an Access 97 database to 2003?; or (3) I want to convert my database from 97 to 2003, AND convert my VB6 code to use 2003, or possibly Visual Studio?

Comment: You should be able to do this using DAO, JRO, or the JetComp.exe utility.  But nothing is going to rewrite any MS Access stuff (UserForms, VBA, etc.) only the data.  Great for a clean Jet database, not so much for a crudded up MDB that MS Access has ever touched.

Comment: Thanks Wayne and Bob77. I want to use VB6 to convert an Access 97 database to Access 2003. This is the first step of my project. After i want convert my VB6 code to Visual Studio. But in two phases, at the moment only the first step.

Comment: My database only have Tables with data and Querys, no forms, no VBA...

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do this in code. Why not just export and import the data and queries using Access?

Comment: I need do it by code because my program is executed in the home of each client of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *DAO* in VB6, create a new database in *JET 4.0* format:

```
DBEngine.CreateDatabase "c:\test\db4.mdb", dbLangGeneral, dbVersion40
```

Then copy all objects from the old database to the new database.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835033(v=office.15).aspx).